# Web.config rewrite that excludes certain URL's needed

Tags: windows, http, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

The standard web.config rewrite to turn all  HTTP into HTTPS works fine

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="http to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" 
    redirectType="Temporary" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

URLS that begin with `HTTP://192.168` should not be rewritten but I've been unable to change the code to do this. I've tried to change the match to `HTTP://192.168` and then negate it but I think that affects the action line

Comment: The section "URLS that begin with should not be rewritten" should say URLS that begin with  "HTTP://192.168" should not be rewritten

Comment: The section change the match to should be change the match to "HTTP://192.168" ........

Comment: Check Mistake 1, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59, and you can check the incoming host name with a regular expression on "192.168". Do some experiments and also learn how to troubleshoot https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules